# @Html.DisplayNameFor() respects [Display] attribute but @Html.DisplayFor() ignores [DisplayFormat] attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this view model:

```cs
public class ConceptViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Message_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Web.ValidationsViewModels))]
    [Display(Name = "ConceptViewModel_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Web.Contracts))]
    public string Concept { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Message_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Web.ValidationsViewModels))]
    [Display(Name = "ConceptViewModel_TotalUnits", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Web.Contracts))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###,###}")] // Ignored by @Html.DisplayFor()
    public decimal TotalUnits { get; set; }
}
```

That view model is inside a collection property of another view model that happens to be the one passed to the view:

```cs
public class ContratConceptsViewModel : BaseClass
{
    public int ContratId { get; set; }

    // This collection
    public List<ConceptViewModel> Concepts { get; set; }

    public ContratConceptsViewModel()
    {
        Concepts = new List<ConceptViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And then, inside the view, I have this code:

```html
@model ContratConceptsViewModel

@foreach (var concept in Model.Concepts)
{
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => concept.Concept) </td> @* Works as expected *@
            <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => concept.TotalUnits) </td> @* Works as expected *@ 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => concept.Concept) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => concept.TotalUnits) </td> @* Doesn't show the correct format *@
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

When I execute this code, the `[Display]` attribute is taken into account, but the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute is totally ignored. What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE:* I have searched for a question like this one, and despite there are many others with a similar title, they are different from this one.

Comment: Is that `,` supposed to be a group separator or a decimal separator? Show us an example of the data, expected format and mistakenly shown format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was all my fault. One of my coworkers created a template for `decimal` inside the folder **Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Decimal.cshtml**. That's why `@Html.DisplayFor()` was ignoring the attribute, it was because it was respecting the template created by my coworker.

Answer (score -1):

You should amend you expressions inside `DisplayFor` and `DisplayNameFor`.
It must be `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalUnits)`, not `@Html.DisplayFor(model => concept.TotalUnits)`.

**UPDATE**

Because you're displaying items from the list `@Html.DisplayFor` will not work properly: it's supposed to work with single model. I would suggest to extract your template for each item into separate file(it's called display template in MVC):

Your display template(it must be placed in DisplayTemplates folder):

```
@model ConceptViewModel
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Concept) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalUnits) </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Concept) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalUnits) </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Your main page:

```
@model ContratConceptsViewModel

@foreach (var concept in Model.Concepts)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => concept, "name of your display template, optional if you follow conventions")
}
```

Here is the [link](https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc/example/30137/display-template) about display templates.

Comment: I have tried with a partial in which the model is `ConceptViewModel` and it didn't work neither. I don't need a display template for the whole `ConceptViewModel`, the problem is just a `decimal` property. Even if I create a template for the whole `ConceptViewModel`, I would have the same problem when I call `DisplayFor()` on the `decimal` property. There's a [default display template](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) for `decimal` created by MVC, and when a format is specified, that template respects it. But not in my case...

Comment: `It must be @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalUnits), not @Html.DisplayFor(model => concept.TotalUnits)` - that does not matter. The attribute will be correctly used even if the right part of the lambda is not connected to the left part. `@Html.DisplayFor will not work properly: it's supposed to work with single model` - that is exactly why the OP is (correctly) using the `model => concept.TotalUnits`.